Lower bound on the order of a graph
Following "Graph Theory" by Reinhard Diestel.

We can bound the order of $G$ from below by assuming that both its minimum degree $d$ and girth $g$ are large. For $d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g\in \mathbb{N}$.

\begin{equation}
n_0(d,g)=
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle
      1+d\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(d-1)^{i} \;\;\;\;\text{if} \;g=:2r+1\; \text{is odd}; \\
\displaystyle
      2\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(d-1)^i \;\;\;\;\text{if} \; g=:2r\; \text{is even}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I am confused by the lower bound defined whenever the girth is of even length. Let $D_i(v)=D_i$ denote the set of vertices at distance $i$ from a given vertex $v$ and $C$ be the shortest cycle in $G$. Observe that $|D_0|=1$ and $|D_1|\geq d$. By induction, pick any $v\in C$ then $|D_i|\geq(d-1)|D_{i-1}|=d(d-1)^{i-1}$. That shows the case where $g$ is odd in $n_0(d,g)$. But for $g$ even I have no idea on why that is the lower bound. Any hints?
Edit: Observe that $|D_i|\geq d(d-1)^{i-1}> 2(d-1)^{i-1}$. So how come the parity of $g$ relates?

What happens if you fuse two adjacent vertexes in the shortest cycle?

Consider two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$.
Let $U_i$ be the vertices that are distance $i$ from $u$, but distance $i+1$ from $v$, and $V_i$ the vertices distance $i$ from $v$ but distance $i+1$ from $u$.
Now you count the number of vertices in $U_i$ and $V_i$ the same way you counted the number in $D_i$. Since the girth is $2r$, none of the sets $U_i$ and $V_i$ can have any vertices in common.
